# Pass custom message to catch error block with throw error

Tags: javascript

I want to create custom error message and be able to read it in my catch block, how can I achieve this? I want to make erorMessage in catch block with the text that `throw Error` passes and be able to display custom error message. However when I try to log (err)

```js
const password = "test";
const repeatPassword = "test1";
let errorMessage = "";

const handleSubmit = () => {
    if(password != repeatPassword) {
    throw Error("Passwords must match");
  }
  
  try {
    console.log("trying");
  } catch(err) {
    errorMessage = err;
    console.log(err);
  }
}

handleSubmit();
```

am I approaching this in wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just move your try above like this

```
    const handleSubmit = () => {
      try {
        console.log("trying");
        if(password != repeatPassword) {
        throw Error("Passwords must match");
        }
      } catch(err) {
        errorMessage = err;
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```